# Можно ли изменить дефолтные настройки primeng компонентов?

Tags: angular, primefaces

Например я хочу задать для **всех** `<p-calendar>` `dateFormat="dd.mm.yy"` по-умолчанию, чтобы не прописывать это каждый раз

Answer (score 1):

Переопределите вывод даты как вам нужно, например:

```
<p-calendar 
  [(ngModel)]="dateValue"
  (onSelect)="onSelect($event)"
  [dataType]="date">
</p-calendar>
```

yourComponent.ts:

```
onSelect(event) {
  let date = new Date(Date.parse(event));
  this.dateValue = `${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вы неправильно поняли суть проблемы. Исправил вопрос